# Angular Display Data From Array

Tags: php, angularjs

I am new to angularJS and has very few knowledge on javascript.

I am trying to retrieve data from database by using the $http.post method. below is what I get from the .php file.

```
 [{
    "ticketid": "1484637895",
    "categoryid": "1",
    "subcategoryid": "2",
    "ciphonenum": "01814149028",
    "calldescription": "The customer wanted to know all the SKU of Bashundhara Baby Diaper and he requested to inform  him through the mail.",
    "ccrreply": "CCR sent him all SKU of Diaper including the M.R.P.",
    "ccraction": "N\/A",
    "output": "N\/A",
    "remarks": "N\/A",
    "contactinfoname": "MD.Masud",
    "ciaddress": "Banani,DOHS\nDhaka."
 }]
```

Here is what  my php file looks like

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

require 'db-config.php';

$ticketid = $data->id;

$sql = "SELECT t.ticketid, t.categoryid, t.subcategoryid, td.ciphonenum,     td.calldescription, td.ccrreply,
td.ccraction, td.output, td.remarks, ci.contactinfoname, ci.ciaddress FROM     ticketdetails td 
INNER JOIN tickets t on t.ticketid = td.ticketid
INNER JOIN contactinfodetails ci ON ci.ciphonenum = td.ciphonenum WHERE     t.ticketid = '$ticketid'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   $data = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($data);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Below is the function in angularjs which generate the post request

```
$scope.showTicket = function() {
        var id = $routeParams.id;
        $http.post('api/showTicket.php',{'id':id}).then(function(response){
            $scope.ticket = response.data;
            console.log($scope.ticket);
        });
    };
```

I want display only the ticketid and calldescription from the array but whenever I assign value like
    $scope.ticketid = $scope.ticket.ticketid;
it says undefined variable. Please help....

Comment: $scope.ticket[0].ticketid

Comment: because you $scope.ticket is an array. So **$scope.ticketid = $scope.ticket[0].ticketid;** can work..

Comment: I tried with $scope.ticketid = $scope.ticket[0].ticketid; but it says undefined variable.

Comment: It worked thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an **array of objects**, and not an **object**.

So instead of doing `$scope.ticketid = $scope.ticket.ticketid`, try:

```
$scope.ticketid = $scope.ticket[0].ticketid;
```

---

As your array only contains one object, it is probably the solution...

Comment: I tried with $scope.ticketid = $scope.ticket[0].ticketid; but it says undefined variable.

Comment: @facebook-391055214411309 Can you accept the answer if it solved your issue please?